# How to access ith member of map?

Tags: c++

I want to access any member of `map` in `c++`.
Like in if I have a 
`map = {(4,3), (5,6), (9,8)}`

and say I want to to get second member of this map. I tried

```
map<int, int>::iterator it = mpp.begin();
cout << (it+1)->first << " " << (it+1)->second << endl;
```

I didn't get any success. Please help me out.

Comment: Take a look at [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next).

Answer (score 1):

Only random access iterators have overloads for `operator+` and `operator-`. Bidirectional iterators such as `std::map::iterator` do not. They can however be advanced linearly by using `std::next` (since C++11) which will

> Return the nth successor of iterator it.

or `std::advance` which

> Increments given iterator it by n elements.

---

PS. Note that the complexity for finding n'th element of a `std::map` has linear complexity. There are other similar data structures provide the features that `std::map` has, but also allow for faster n'th member lookup. So, and alternative data structure might more appropriate for your use case.

For example, a binary search tree can be augmented with the size of each subtree. Such structure is named order statistic tree. For the small linear increase in memory overhead, it gives O(log n) complexity for finding n'th element.

Answer (score 0):

I rather applied a simple method. 
Say I have to get `jth` element from the begging.

```
map<int, int>::iterator it = mpp.begin();
while(j--)
          it++;
cout << it->first << " " << it -> second << endl;
```